# how to update two or more tables simultaneously in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have more than one tables to update I am able to upload text in one table but I want to upload different text in all the tables in a one go in `shiny app`. I searched a lot but I didn't get the way to do it as I am new to `shiny app`. Below is my code. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
error7 <- read.csv(file.path("D:/puma/error7.csv"), sep = "," , header =TRUE)

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shinyUI( fluidPage(theme=shinytheme("readable"),
                     titlePanel(h3("PUMA", style = "color:black")),
                     sidebarLayout(
                       sidebarPanel(
                         tags$head(
                           tags$style("body {background-color: pink; }")),
                         textInput("Possible.cause", label="Add a new Possible.cause ", value="Enter Possible.cause"),
                         textInput("Check", label="Add a new Check", value="Enter Check"),
                         textInput("Remedy", label="Add a new Remedy", value="Enter Remedy"),
                         actionButton("addButton", "UPLOAD!")
                       ),
                       mainPanel(
                         tableOutput("table"), width = 12)
                     )))

server = function(input, output) {    
 values <- reactiveValues()
 values$df <- error7 
  row.names(error7) <- NULL

    observe({

   if(input$addButton > 0) {

    newLine <- isolate(c(input$Possible.cause, input$Check, input$Remedy))
  isolate(values$df <- rbind(as.matrix(values$df), unlist(newLine)))
  write.csv(values$df,file.path("D:/puma/error7.csv"), sep = "," ,
            row.names = FALSE,append=FALSE)
}
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({values$df}, include.rownames=F)
 }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong with your code. I am going through it step by step:

- 1.1, It is not an error, but you refer to a local file for reading and writing csv files. It will work fine, until you deploy your app
  and the server doesn't have the file in the specified location. I
  changed it to the app's root folder `"./error7.csv"` (and also copied the file to the project folder). *You can leave it the way it is if you want*.
- 1.2, Use `stringsAsFactors = F` to avoid having to deal with `factor`.

Code:

```
error7 <- read.csv(file.path("./error7.csv"), sep = "," , header =TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

- 2, Setting `row.names` doesn't matter since you're not using it.

We can remove this line: `row.names(error7) <- NULL`

- 3.1, Use `observeEvent` instead of `observe` when you only want to handle a single event such as a button click:
- 3.2, `isolate` is not needed in this case
- 3.3, Modified the `rbind` part: using `names(newLine) <- names(values$df)` the `data.frame` and the `newLine` `vector` can be
  binded together.
- 3.4, `write.csv` uses comma for the separator anyways so there is no need to specify it. `append=FALSE` is not used either.

Code:

```
observeEvent(input$addButton,{
    newLine <- c(input$Possible.cause, input$Check, input$Remedy)
    names(newLine) <- names(values$df)
    values$df <- rbind(values$df, newLine)
    write.csv(values$df,file.path("./error7.csv"), row.names = FALSE)
  })
```

Complete code:

```
error7 <- read.csv(file.path("./error7.csv"), sep = "," , header =TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shinyUI( fluidPage(theme=shinytheme("readable"),
                         titlePanel(h3("PUMA", style = "color:black")),
                         sidebarLayout(
                           sidebarPanel(
                             tags$head(
                               tags$style("body {background-color: pink; }")),
                             textInput("Possible.cause", label="Add a new Possible.cause ", value="Enter Possible.cause"),
                             textInput("Check", label="Add a new Check", value="Enter Check"),
                             textInput("Remedy", label="Add a new Remedy", value="Enter Remedy"),
                             actionButton("addButton", "UPLOAD!")
                           ),
                           mainPanel(
                             tableOutput("table"), width = 12)
                         )))

server = function(input, output) {    
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- error7 

  observeEvent(input$addButton,{
    newLine <- c(input$Possible.cause, input$Check, input$Remedy)
    names(newLine) <- names(values$df)
    values$df <- rbind(values$df, newLine)
    write.csv(values$df,file.path("./error7.csv"), row.names = FALSE)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({values$df}, include.rownames=F)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks @GyD for your answer but your code is working same as mine. I didn't find answer to my question. Also thanks for your suggestions and time.

Comment: what would you like to achieve then?